# Running Specflow tests in parallel: BoDi.ObjectContainerException : An object has been resolved for this interface already

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nunit, specflow

I'm trying to run my Specflow tests in parallel. I've created an Assembly.cs file with

```
[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
[assembly: LevelOfParallelism(10)]
```

The code snippet below gives me the "**An object has been resolved for this interface already**" error when the tests are run in parallel, in the `CreateTestData()` method, at the line with `_container.RegisterInstanceAs(_driver, typeof(IWebDriver));`. If I run the tests sequentially, they pass.

```
 public class BootstrapSelenium
 {
        private static IObjectContainer _container = new ObjectContainer();
        private static IWebDriver? _driver;
        public BootstrapSelenium(IObjectContainer container) => _container = container;

        [BeforeTestRun]
        public static void LoadDriver()
        {
            var appSettings = new AppSettings();
            Configuration.Bind(appSettings);
            _container.RegisterInstanceAs(appSettings, typeof(AppSettings));
        }

        [BeforeScenario]
        public void CreateTestData()
        {
            _driver = CreateChromeDriver();
            _container.RegisterInstanceAs(_driver, typeof(IWebDriver));
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _driver?.Close();
        }

        [AfterTestRun]
        public static void CloseAll()
        {
            _driver?.Quit();
        }

        private IWebDriver CreateChromeDriver()
        {
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
            options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
            options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
            var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
            return driver;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Which unit test provider are you using?

Comment: Your code does not appear to be valid C# ... The `BootstrapSelenium` method has the signature of a contructor, but does not have the same name as the class.

Comment: Hi @GregBurghardt thank you for your note, I've fixed the code with the right constructor now, my bad. 
I'm using NUnit as a unit test provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add `[ThreadStatic]` to mark the _container and _driver fields. In this way, these fields will be unique for each thread. More details about ThreadStatic attribute can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threadstaticattribute?view=net-7.0).

```
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static IObjectContainer _container = new ObjectContainer();

    [ThreadStatic]
    private static IWebDriver? _driver;
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to work now, I was not expecting this change to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To run tests in parallel, the `_container` and `_driver` fields should be instance variables, rather than static. This does present a challenge for the `AppSettings` object. You can still load this object from a static context, but you would need to register it in the DI container before each test:

```
public class BootstrapSelenium
{
    private static AppSettings appSettings;

    private readonly IObjectContainer _container;
    private IWebDriver? _driver;

    public BootstrapSelenium(IObjectContainer container) => _container = container;

    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void LoadDriver()
    {
        if (appSettings == null)
        {
            appSettings = new AppSettings();
            Configuration.Bind(appSettings);
        }
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void CreateTestData()
    {
        _container.RegisterInstanceAs(appSettings);
        _driver = CreateChromeDriver();
        _container.RegisterInstanceAs<IWebDriver>(_driver);
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _driver?.Dispose();
    }

    private IWebDriver CreateChromeDriver()
    {
        // no changes need to be made here
    }
}
```

You must dispose of the web driver after each test. Each parallel test needs its own web driver.

Comment: but I don't want to reuse the app setting because I don't need them anymore after the [BeforeTestRun] finishes the execution

Comment: @R.B.M. then why did you register the app settings in the DI container to begin with?